# How to draw a box around the text when i've selected the text with mouse in Text area?

Tags: java, swing, textarea

I have used

```
textArea1=new TextArea();
String s=textArea1.getSelectedText();
g.drawRect(s.length(),s.length(),s.length(),s.length());
```

but its not working as expected.

Comment: Where are you using this graphics object ? More code is needed to ascertain your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You question is confusing. You use a Swing tag, but you also use a TextArea text which is an AWT component, not a Swing component.

I would suggest that you do use Swing and that you use a JTextArea. In this case you can add a "highlight" to the specified. Here is a custom class that allows you to use a [Rectangle Painter](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) for this highlight.